# How to deserialize JSON with different heirs

Tags: java, json, groovy, jackson

There are several types of json, I will give two types for an example:

```
{
  "name": "dataUpdated",
  "version": 102,
  "eventTime": "2021-06-24",
  "payload": {
    "id": 158420,
    "name": 446970,
    "date": "2021-06-16",
    "type": "A"
}

{
  "name": "dataError",
  "version": 102,
  "eventTime": "2021-06-25",
  "payload": {
    "error": 666,
    "errorMsg": "forbidden"
}
```

Only the payload's structure changes

I have a class MessageDto

```
class MessageDto {
    
        @JsonProperty("name")
        String name
    
        @JsonProperty("version")
        Integer version
    
        @JsonProperty("eventTime")
        String eventTime
        
        @JsonProperty("payload")
        Payload payload 
    }
```

Class Payload is empty, I just use it as a marker and inherit two classes from it:

```
DataUpdatedDto extends Payload {

        @JsonProperty("id")
        BigInteger id

        @JsonProperty("name")
        String name

        @JsonProperty("date")
        String date
        
        @JsonProperty("type")
        String type

}

DataErrorDto extends Payload {
    
            @JsonProperty("error")
            Integer error
    
            @JsonProperty("errorMsg")
            String errorMsg
    }
```

How to explain to the deserializer in which of the descendants of Payload I want to deserialize?

Comment: if you are using `ObjectMapper` it will ask you for the class that you want to deserialize into

Comment: You're looking for `@JsonTypeInfo`.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-
 I cannot figure out how to declare JsonTypeName if it is the same for all: "payload". The choice of the name of the class in which to deserialize depends on the attribute MessageDto.name

Comment: `JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY` is for precisely this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to set the following things up:

- Using `@JsonTypeInfo` to set up the mechanism to apply some strategy
  to dispatch to certain implementing classes

  - `include=JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY` because of what you want
    to dispatch is not *inside* payload, but on the same level of the
    map
  - `use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property="name"` to read the value from
    the `name` property to do the dispatch
- Using `@JsonSubTypes` with the `@JsonSubTypes.Type` setup

  - e.g. `@JsonSubTypes.Type(value=DataUpdatedDto, name="dataUpdated")`
    to associate the class `DataUpdatedDto` with the value of
    `dataUpdated` inside the parent map

Full example

```
@Grab('com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.12.4')
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.*
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.*

class MessageDto {

    @JsonProperty("name")
    String name

    @JsonProperty("version")
    Integer version

    @JsonProperty("eventTime")
    String eventTime

    @JsonProperty("payload")
    @JsonTypeInfo(include=JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY, use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property="name")
    @JsonSubTypes([
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=DataUpdatedDto, name="dataUpdated"),
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=DataErrorDto, name="dataError")
    ])
    Payload payload 
}

interface Payload {}

class DataUpdatedDto implements Payload {

    @JsonProperty("id")
    BigInteger id

    @JsonProperty("name")
    String name

    @JsonProperty("date")
    String date

    @JsonProperty("type")
    String type

}

class DataErrorDto implements Payload {

    @JsonProperty("error")
    Integer error

    @JsonProperty("errorMsg")
    String errorMsg
}

def objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)

def updated = objectMapper.readValue("""
{
  "name": "dataUpdated",
  "version": 102,
  "eventTime": "2021-06-24",
  "payload": {
    "id": 158420,
    "name": 446970,
    "date": "2021-06-16",
    "type": "A"
  }
}
""", MessageDto)

assert updated.payload instanceof DataUpdatedDto

def error = objectMapper.readValue("""
{
  "name": "dataError",
  "version": 102,
  "eventTime": "2021-06-25",
  "payload": {
    "error": 666,
    "errorMsg": "forbidden"
  }
}
""", MessageDto)

assert error.payload instanceof DataErrorDto
```